# regex expression where it can extract the number positioned at the semi end in the string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=94771b6589b01526ad0cf6e5c4d01945

I need help in extracting the number substring from a file name
currently for file format - `'monkey_eats_mango_everyday_202002.txt'`
we are doing like this

```
select regexp_substr('monkey_eats_mango_everyday_202002.txt', '\d+') as parameter12a 
from dual;
```

result-

```
202002
```

which in turn used in larger query to get the last date of this date like this

```
select to_char(last_day(to_date(regexp_substr('monkey_eats_mango_everyday_202002.txt', '\d+'),  'yyyymm')), 'yyyymmdd') as parameter 
from dual ;
```

result-

```
20200229
```

Now the file format has changed, so we have - `'donkey_eats_pines_cones_20192301_7771234_everyday_202002.txt'`

In this file format there are numbers at other places like 201943_7771234 which can be dates or any random number, so I need regex expression which can extract  202002 from file format

```
select regexp_substr('donkey_eats_pines_cones_201943_7771234_everyday_202002.txt', '\d+') as parameter12a 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `\.` to anchor your digits match to next to the period in the file name, and then use a capture group around the digits to get just the digits in the output, using the 6th parameter to [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions138.htm#SQLRF06303) to indicate that you only want group 1 in the output:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('donkey_eats_pines_cones_201943_7771234_everyday_202002.txt', '(\d+)\.', 1, 1, NULL, 1) AS parameter12a 
FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
202002
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e25d60f8eafaee4a448fc811f2629cf)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use nested expressions: inner returns file extension and the date (that precedes that extension), and outer fetches date itself.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'donkey_eats_pines_cones_201943_7771234_everyday_202002.txt' from dual)
  3  select regexp_substr(regexp_substr(col, '\d+.\w+$'), '\d+') result From test
  4  /

RESULT
------
202002

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
select reverse(split_part(reverse(r.r ), '.', 2)) from 
(
SELECT reverse(split_part(reverse('donkey_eats_pines_cones_20192301_7771234_everyday_202002.txt'), '_', 1)) as r
)as r
```

ANS : 
202002